# Rails 4.1 Variants not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use actionpack Variants in my rails 4.1 website.

I'm following the rails guide, but it doesn't work.

In my application controller

```
before_action :set_request_variant

  private 

  def set_request_variant
    request.variant = :mobile if browser.mobile?
  end
```

I have Browser gem, and with iPhone user agent it return true so everything here is ok.

In my controller

```
  def show
    @event = Event.find params[:id]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.html.mobile 
    end
  end
```

I have an `application+mobile.html.haml` and a `_header+mobile.html.haml` but the server serves always the standard layout and standards views...

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think your layout and view template names might be the problem.  Does it work if you try `application.html+phone.haml` and `_header.html+mobile.haml` instead?

The format I've suggested is consistent with the Rails 4.1 release notes [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html).